# How to fix null pointer exception when creating a gameHelper with LibGDX and BaseGameUtils?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am currently working on my first game (which I will NOT shameless promote), but I am trying to set up a leaderboard, but when I try to initialize my GameHelper, I get an exception. I couldn't find any answers and I would appreciate any help.

Code:

```
package com.aidanstrong.runner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelperListener, PlayServices{

private final static int requestCode = 1;
private GameHelper gameHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new MyGame(this), config);
    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this,GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    gameHelper.setup(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}

@Override
public boolean signIn() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void logIn() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }
}

@Override
public void submitScore(int score) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),"CgkIlKy-68IeEAIQAQ",score);
}


@Override
public void getLeaderboard() {
    Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(),"CgkIlKy-68IeEAIQAQ");
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
}
}
```

the error I receive is

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.aidanstrong.runner/com.aidanstrong.runner.AndroidLauncher}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference" on line 21.

EDIT:
I tried it out and got a new error, moving all the statements in the constructor to before gameHelper.setup(this) I get the error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.aidanstrong.runner, PID: 11950
>                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zza;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzc;)V
>   in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api' appears in
>   /data/app/com.aidanstrong.runner-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:276)
>                                                                               at
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:309)
>                                                                               at
>   com.aidanstrong.runner.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:32)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)'

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aidanstrong.runner"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.22" >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/secondicon"
        android:label="Jump Man"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
        android:name="com.aidanstrong.runner.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="Jump Man"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
</application>
```

Comment: I don't have LibGDX installed at the moment - according to your IDE - which is line 21?  It looks like the Android Application is not initialised yet by the time you try to make a "this" reference to it.

Comment: @Ewald it's the line gameHelper = new GameHelper....Etc.

Comment: I think that explains it - move that to the onCreate() method rather, which is called during the Android lifecycle.

Comment: See edit please! It changed the error, but we're getting somewhere!

Comment: Please update the code as well, so that I can see what changed.

Comment: @Ewald updated it! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should delete that entire empty constructor, it's not needed and could cause issues with the Android lifecycle as it doesn't allow the base constructors to kick in.  Try that quickly please.

Comment: @Ewald same error but the constructor is removed

Comment: That's good - it's a process of elimination.  Are you using ProGuard by any chance?  That could be stripping out / renaming methods.

Comment: @Ewald Nope, I don't remember doing it at least!

Comment: It looks like something could be missing from your manifest file, but it's hard to tell without running the project.  Is this a sample you are working from? Did you include all the "meta-data" tags from the sample manifest file in your new one?

Comment: Ill show you my manifest file, its updated as of right now.

Comment: It seems that it can't find the Google Play Services method that you are calling. Is this on an emulator?

Comment: @Ewald I'm not 100% what your asking but I think it's a no

Comment: Are you deploying to a physical device, or an Android emulator?

Comment: @Ewald physical device

Comment: It looks like it's not finding the Google Play services it's expecting.  Can you try an emulator, making sure it includes the Google API's? For example, an Android 5.0 emulator.  Just to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: It Still crashes

Comment: Ah, I'll have to get it running this side to debug. It's just before 01:00am, I need to catch some sleep. I'll install LibGDX in the morning and see if I can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your meta-data inside  `<application` tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Remove default constructor of `AndroidLauncher`

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IGoogleServices {

private GameHelper gameHelper;
private final static int REQUEST_CODE_UNUSED = 9002;
private static final String TAG = "[" + AndroidLauncher.class.getSimpleName() + "]";

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    GameHelper.GameHelperListener gameHelperListener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded(){}

        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {}
    };

    //gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
    gameHelper.setup(gameHelperListener);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    initialize(new MyGame(this), config);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void signIn() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log in failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

 @Override
public void signOut() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //gameHelper.signOut();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log out failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

 @Override
public void submitScore(long score) {
    if (isSignedIn()) Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);
}

@Override
public void showScores() {
    if(isSignedIn())
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_id)), REQUEST_CODE_UNUSED);
    else
        signIn();
}

@Override
public boolean isSignedIn() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void start() {
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}
```

IGoogleServices is an interface in `core` module that I use for Interfacing with `android` module.

Comment: I changed the manifest file (see update), and I just removed my default no-args constructor. Yet I still receive the same error.

Comment: please show `build.gradle` file ? It's looks version mismatch issue.